# array assignment access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I’ve read many Q&A's which seemed similar to this problem but haven’t found any answers yet:
I have to make some assignments to a dynamic byte array in the `fillbyte` function like this:

```
int Error;
result = fillbyte (&Error);
```

if I comment the line shown below, everything works fine. but if that line gets executed, the second time that this function is called, access violation exception will be raised however the first time the code runs properly and everything goes alright. I can’t seem to find the problem with this line of code or another way to fill the array with password bytes.

```
Bool fillbyte(int *Error)
{
    byte BCC;
    byte *Packet1 = new byte;
    *Packet1 = 0x01;
    *(Packet1+1) = 'P';
    *(Packet1+2) = '1';
    *(Packet1+3) = STX;
    *(Packet1+4) = '(';
    int add = sizeof(readingprops.password)*2;
    for(int i=0;i<add;i++)
    {
        *(Packet1+(5+i)) = readingprops.password[i];     //this line raises the problem
    }
    *(Packet1+add+5) = ')';
    *(Packet1+add+6) = ETX;
    BCC = calc.CalcBCC(Packet1,add+7);
    *(Packet1+add+7) = BCC;
    SerialPort.Write(Packet1,add+8);
    delete Packet1;
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well, allocating one `byte` and then using it as it had more will do that.

Comment: Replace `byte *Packet1 = new byte;` with `byte *Packet1 = Readstr;`

Comment: but the size of the array is unknown to me. Should i work with a big initialized array and the number of bytes i fill in it? i have lots of suck blocks in the same function and i was planning to use that 'Packet1' in all the blocks as it is only an address

Comment: @ctn no the `Readstr` doesn't have anything to do with `Packet1` i should edit my function not to be misunderstood

Comment: @arianoo You know the size: it's `add + 8`, you even say so in the call to `SerialPort.Write` (but your computation of `add` looks weird).

Comment: I understand but i didn't want to specify a size for this array so that i assign to it some more times in the same function but i guess i'll have to initialize it with size

Comment: If you are working in C++ (which you do, according to the tags), you can just use an `std::vector<int>` and forget about initialisation or size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how it can ever work.  You allocate one byte on the heap but treat it as multiple bytes:

```
byte *Packet1 = new byte;
*Packet1 = 0x01;
*(Packet1+1) = 'P';  // !!!
*(Packet1+2) = '1';  // !!!
*(Packet1+3) = STX;  // !!!
*(Packet1+4) = '(';  // !!!
```

Comment: Or rather `byte *Packet1 = new byte[add+8];`.

Comment: Your solution works completely fine and for my aim, I delete and initialize the array again in each block with the new size I want.
Thanks so much for pointing out my problem

Answer (score 3):

Here you allocate just *one* byte

```
byte *Packet1 = new byte;
```

and then use the pointer beyond the allocated memory

```
*(Packet1+1) = 'P';
*(Packet1+2) = '1';
*(Packet1+3) = STX;
*(Packet1+4) = '(';
```

This causes undefined behaviour, sometimes it may work. So you want something like

```
byte Packet1 = new byte[size]
```

where size is appropriate for your needs (probably `add + 8`, since this is the amount of bytes you write to in that function). Then delete it with `delete[]`. You could also use stack allocation, or `std::vector<byte>` since this is c++.